# jQuery Find Element Using Property

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to locate some elements from a table. The problem is that I might not know all the time the type of the element. That means an element can be a simple TD or a SELECT. But since both have text associated with it I want to retrieve the element if that has the text property.

```
$($(rows[i]).find("element that has property text")[0]).text();
```

UPDATE 1: I updated the code and the td text node has a value but the currentRow.triggerType is returned empty.

```
currentRow.triggerType = $($(rows[i]).find('td')[0]).filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3; 
        }).text();
```

Comment: That just seems heavy and inefficient. Why can´t you just use IDs or classes? `TD` elements has a text/innerHTML while `SELECT` elements has options. What should it be looking for?

Comment: Very old code written previously. No ids or classes are associated with the elements.

Comment: What do you mean by 'text property' ? You mean the DOM nodes that can have a text node child ?

Comment: I mean like this $(td).text() // correct and $("select").text(); Maybe text property is the wrong word I should use innerText property.

Comment: @Stefan it should return the value returned from the jQuery text() function.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a custom filter function - in the following example, we reduce the result set to items that contain a text node (`nodeType == 3`)

```
$('td').filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text()
```

Update

Your selector should be

```
$(rows[i]).find('td').first().filter(...
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a one liner way without using the function.

Comment: No. And if you want it on one line, take out the line breaks! Why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question, but would this work?

```
$(rows[i]).filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() !== '';
}).text();
```

You can also try this:

```
$(rows[i]).not(':empty').text();
```

Comment: Basically I have an HTML table. Table has rows and cells. Some cells have text node and some cells have dropdownlist. I want to select the text value using the text() function of jQuery from the td and from the dropdownlist.

Comment: I "love" those kind of questions, you answer but you don't know what the question was... **=)**

Comment: @gdoron: The question's kinda confusing, but I figured maybe my answer would help, or at least point him in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the contains selector?

http://jsfiddle.net/W9EMM/

Comment: No I am not looking for contains. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It´s not clear what you´d like to do with the values but here are some ways to get them;

```
$('td:first, select').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).val() || $(this).text();
    console.log(text);
});
```

If some `td` elements contains `select` elements;

```
$('td').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $select = $this.find('select:first'),
        text

    text = ($select.length == 0) ? $this.text() : $select.val();
    console.log(text);
});
```